# VS 2019 - quick action menu items missing

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellisense, automated-refactoring, xml-comments

I have two Win10 PC, both with the same installation VS2019 Enterpsrise(Version 16.11.15). Almost the same extensions. But in one VS installation, quick action menu and it's options look like on the picture below.

[image: Adding missing param nodes]

- add missing param nodes
- make method synchronous
- etc.

The other installation is missing every single item above "Change signature.." item.
[image: Missing menu items]

What am I missing? Can someone help me with this? I'm the most interested in "Add missing param nodes".
I've tried to find over what could be the extension that is incorporating this feature but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see in the first screenshot that CS1573 means have no matching param tag in the XML comment.

So you should generate an XML file that contains the documentation comments.

You can refer to the following step to enable this option:

1. Go to project>Properties>Build>Output
2. select Generate a file containing API documentation
   [image]
3. Now you can check the quick action menu, you will see “Add missing param nodes” in it.
   [image]

Comment: thank you on this note. I was not aware of this